# Efficient PyTorch DataLoader collate_fn function for inputs of various dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, mini-batch

I'm having trouble writing a custom `collate_fn` function for the PyTorch `DataLoader` class. I need the custom function because my inputs have different dimensions.

I'm currently trying to write the baseline implementation of the [Stanford MURA paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06957). The dataset has a set of labeled studies. A study may contain more than one image. I created a custom `Dataset`class that stacks these multiple images using `torch.stack`.

The stacked tensor is then provided as input to the model and the list of outputs is averaged to obtain a single output. This implementation works fine with `DataLoader` when `batch_size=1`. However, when I try to set the `batch_size` to 8, as is the case in the original paper, the `DataLoader` fails since it uses `torch.stack` to stack the batch and the inputs in my batch have variable dimensions (since each study can have multiple number of images).

In order to fix this, I tried to implement my custom `collate_fn` function.

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    imgs = [item['images'] for item in batch]
    targets = [item['label'] for item in batch]
    targets = torch.LongTensor(targets)
    return imgs, targets
```

Then in my training epoch loop, I loop through each batch like this:

```
for image, label in zip(*batch):
    label = label.type(torch.FloatTensor)
    # wrap them in Variable
    image = Variable(image).cuda()  
    label = Variable(label).cuda()
    # forward
    output = model(image)
    output = torch.mean(output)
    loss = criterion(output, label, phase)
```

However, this does not give me any improved timings on the epoch and still takes as long as it did with a batch size of only 1. I've also tried setting the batch size to 32 and that does not improve the timings either.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: "*this does not give me any improved timings*" why should it be faster?

Comment: @Ivan I would expect increasing the batch size to improve total training time as more samples will be processed within a batch.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting problem! If I understand you correctly (and also checking the abstract of the paper), you have *40,561 images from 14,863 studies, where each study is manually labeled by radiologists as either normal or abnormal.*

I believe the reason why you had the issue you faced was, say, for example, you created a stack for,

1. study A - 12 images
2. study B - 13 images
3. study C - 7 images
4. study D - 1 image, etc.

And you try to use a batch size of 8 during training which would fail when it gets to study D.

Therefore, is there a reason why we want to average the list of outputs in a study to fit a single label? Otherwise, I would simply collect all 40,561 images, assign the same label to all images from the same study (such that list of outputs in A is compared with a list of 12 labels).

Therefore, with a single dataloader you can shuffle across studies (if desired) and use the desired batch size during training.

I see this question has been around for a while, I hope it helps someone in the future :)